# Как менять прокси в браузере не перезагружая его SELENIUM

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, proxy

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import ProxyType, Proxy
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


with open('proxy', 'r') as f:
    array = f.read().splitlines()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/alexandr/geckodriver')

counter = 0
for _ in range(10):
    PROXY = array[counter]
    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
        "httpProxy": PROXY,
        "ftpProxy": PROXY,
        "sslProxy": PROXY,
        "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    }
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(50)
    try:
        driver.get("https://2ip.ru/")
    except:
        driver.quit()
    else:
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'd_clipaaargaargfsgd_button'))
            )
        except TimeoutException:
            counter += 1
    time.sleep(7)
```

Такой метод не работает, как я понял прокси нужно указывать перед запуском браузера, но как можно иначе?

Comment: в теории это можно было бы сделать через страницу "about:config", так настройки прокси применяться на лету. Но вы не можете навигировать по "about:config" стандартным `find_element_by` так как это XUL страница, а не web-страница. Но ладно, можно написать JS код и сделать execute_script(), это выберет вам нужную ячейку и даже попытается изменить переменную. Если это Boolean занчение (Да, Нет - True, False) то всё сработает. Но если вам нужно изменить строку, как напимер IP или порт, то ФФ покажет окно подтверждения в котором нужно нажать Да.

Comment: То есть, да это возможно. На странице "about:config", с помощью `execute_script()` изменить параметр, и с помощью Python управляя мышкой или клавиатурой нажать "Да" в окне подтверждения.

Comment: Но если честно, я не вижу в таком геморе смысла. По моему проще перезагрузить браузер, и если вам нужны Куки или Реверы, то просто забрать их с сайта до перезагрузки, и использовать в браузере с новым Прокси

Comment: Зачем вам менять прокси без перезагрузки?

Comment: Ну или вы можете попробовать использовать ветку Firefox ESR если там страница "about:config" сделана как web, а не как xul. Но это я оставлю вам на исследование)

Comment: Я тут глянул, по странице `about:preferences` можно навигировать обычным `find_element_by...`, и вероятно можно будет поменять настройки proxy.